# MultiIndexing gives me Nan when i create new

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I tried to create a multi index Dataframe. I followed the documentation but I got stacked. Hear is the code below:

```
arrays1 = [
    ['Nigeria','Nigeria','Ethiopia','Ethiopia','Zambia','Zambia','Egypt','Egypt'],
    ['2014','2009','2015','2011','2013','2007','2016','2013']
]
statistics  = pd.DataFrame({"number_of_firms": [310,310,372,372,152,152,282,282], "panel": ['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes']})
statistics1 = pd.DataFrame(statistics, index=arrays1)
statistics1
```

**I got this output**

```
statistics1
```

I just want to understand why it gives me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arrays1 = [ ['Nigeria','Nigeria','Ethiopia','Ethiopia','Zambia','Zambia','Egypt','Egypt'], ['2014','2009','2015','2011','2013','2007','2016','2013'] ] 
print(arrays1)
statistics  = pd.DataFrame({"number_of_firms": [310,310,372,372,152,152,282,282], "panel": ['yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes','yes']}) 
print(statistics)
```

and we get

```
[['Nigeria', 'Nigeria', 'Ethiopia', 'Ethiopia', 'Zambia', 'Zambia', 'Egypt', 'Egypt'], ['2014', '2009', '2015', '2011', '2013', '2007', '2016', '2013']]
   number_of_firms panel
0              310   yes
1              310   yes
2              372   yes
3              372   yes
4              152   yes
5              152   yes
6              282   yes
7              282   yes
```

now setting it up your way we get

```
statistics1 = pd.DataFrame(statistics, index=arrays1) 
print(statistics1)

               number_of_firms panel
Nigeria  2014              NaN   NaN
         2009              NaN   NaN
Ethiopia 2015              NaN   NaN
         2011              NaN   NaN
Zambia   2013              NaN   NaN
         2007              NaN   NaN
Egypt    2016              NaN   NaN
         2013              NaN   NaN
```

Which is what the null is.  Now you are getting this as there is no match between the index you are assigning it and the columns in the dataframe.

Now look at

```
statistics['country'] = ['Nigeria','Nigeria','Ethiopia','Ethiopia','Zambia','Zambia','Egypt','Egypt']
statistics['year'] = ['2014','2009','2015','2011','2013','2007','2016','2013'] 
print (statistics)
statistics2 = statistics.set_index(['country', 'year'])
print(statistics2)

   number_of_firms panel   country  year
0              310   yes   Nigeria  2014
1              310   yes   Nigeria  2009
2              372   yes  Ethiopia  2015
3              372   yes  Ethiopia  2011
4              152   yes    Zambia  2013
5              152   yes    Zambia  2007
6              282   yes     Egypt  2016
7              282   yes     Egypt  2013
```

so here we have attached the columns to the data we want as an index

and here is setting up the index.

```
               number_of_firms panel
country  year                       
Nigeria  2014              310   yes
         2009              310   yes
Ethiopia 2015              372   yes
         2011              372   yes
Zambia   2013              152   yes
         2007              152   yes
Egypt    2016              282   yes
         2013              282   yes
```

so setting the index is looking to take the columns of the data we already have and moving it to the index.

Comment: really appreciate. thanks for the pretty answers. so its because the values in the column doesnt mach with the index. is it possible to use `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`